# Return submitted data to the same form

Tags: visualforce

I have a simple visualforce page containing two input field and a submit button. When I give some input and hit the submit button, the data will save in
sfdc database. Here I want to display the submitted data in that same form after submission. Please help me to do this.

```
<div id="classificationForm" class="pop_container">
    <apex:form id="theForm"> 
        <style>
            input[type=text] {
                width: 100%;
                padding: 12px 20px;
                margin: 8px 0;
                box-sizing: none;
                border: none;
                border-bottom: 1px solid red;
                outline: none;
            }
            input[type=text]:focus {
                background-color: white;
            }

            input[type=radio] { margin-left: 100px;}
            .radioClass { margin-left: -100px;}

            .divider{
            width:10px;
            height:auto;
            display:inline-block;
            }

            mark{
                background-color: white;
                color: red;
            }
        </style>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <br/>
                <p><b>Is your data subject to any restrictions?</b></p>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <apex:selectRadio id="theRadio" onclick="radioval();" value="{!restrict}" styleClass="radioClass">
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="restricted" itemLabel="Restriced"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="notRestricted" itemLabel="Not Restriced" />
                </apex:selectRadio>
            </tr>
        </table>                  

        <br/>

        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td ><p1><font color = "red">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Customer Name</b>:</font><p></p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[Customer Name]<apex:input type="text"  value="{!CustomerName}"/></p1></td>
                <td ><font color = "red">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Project Name</b>:</font><p></p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[Project Name]<input type="text"  id="projectName"/></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <td ><font color = "red">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>NDA(Optional)</b>:</font><p></p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[Reference Number]<apex:input type="text"  value="{!nda}"/></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </tr>

        </table>

        <br/>
        <p><b>1 Does this case have any data that is subject to Handling restrictions?<mark>*</mark></b></p>
        <hr size="10px" color="black"/>

        <table>
            <td style="padding-right: 20px">
                <apex:outputText >  
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!ExportR}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Export Restrictions
                </apex:outputText>

            </td>
            <td style="padding-right: 20px">
                <apex:outputText >
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!thirdParty}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;3rd Party Restrictions
                </apex:outputText>
            </td>




        </table>

        <br/>
        <p><i><b>1a What type of export restrictions apply?</b></i></p>
        <hr size="10px" color="black"/>

        <table>
            <td style="padding-right: 20px">
                <apex:outputText >

                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!itar}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;ITAR
                </apex:outputText>

            </td>

            <td style="padding-right: 20px">
                <apex:outputText >
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!eccn}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;ECN/ECCN
                </apex:outputText>
            </td>

            <td>
                <apex:outputText >
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!idontknow}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;I don't Know
                </apex:outputText>
            </td>       

        </table>

        <br/>
        <p><i><b>1b Please specify ECN/ECCN nubers that apply to your case data.</b></i></p>
        <hr size="10px" color="black"/>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-right: 20px">
                    <apex:outputText >
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!E001}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;3E001
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
                <td >
                    <apex:outputText >
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!E002}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;3E002
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
                <td style="padding-right: 20px">
                    <apex:outputText >
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!E003}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;3E003
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
                <td style="padding-right: 20px">
                    <apex:outputText >
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!E991}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;3E991
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td style="padding-right: 20px">
                    <apex:outputText >
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!fourE001}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;4E001
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
                <td style="padding-right: 20px">
                    <apex:outputText >
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!fourE992}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;4E992
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
                <td style="padding-right: 20px">
                    <apex:outputText >
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!fiveE001}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;5E001
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
                <td style="padding-right: 20px">
                    <apex:outputText >
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!fiveE991}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;5E991
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td style="padding-right: 20px">
                    <apex:outputText >
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!fiveE002}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;5E002
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
                <td style="padding-right: 20px">
                    <apex:outputText >
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!fiveE992}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;5E992
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
                <td style="padding-right: 20px">
                    <apex:outputText >
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!EAR99}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;EAR99
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
                <td style="padding-right: 20px">
                    <apex:outputText >
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!nineE515}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;9E515
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td style="padding-right: 20px">
                    <apex:outputText >
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!others}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Others
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>

                <td><apex:input type="text" value="{!others}"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <br/>

        <p><i><b>2 Are you including any 3rd party IP from the following companies?</b></i></p>
        <hr size="10px" color="black"/>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-right: 20px">
                    <apex:outputText >
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!ARM}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;ARM
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td> 

                <td style="padding-right: 20px">
                    <apex:outputText >
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!Intel}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Intel
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
                <td style="padding-right: 20px">
                    <apex:outputText >
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!TSMC}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;TSMC
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
                <td style="padding-right: 20px">
                    <apex:outputText >
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!IBM_Global}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;IBM GLobal Foundries
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-right: 20px">
                    <apex:outputText >
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!Synopsys}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Synopsys
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>

        <br/>

        <p>
           <i><b>3 Is there a need to deny access to the data by persons located in the following countries (select all that apply)?</b></i>
        </p>
        <hr size="10px" color="black"/>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-right: 20px">
                    <apex:outputText >
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!japan}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Japan
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td> 

                <td style="padding-right: 20px">
                    <apex:outputText >
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!india}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;India
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
                <td style="padding-right: 20px">
                    <apex:outputText >
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!china}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;China
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
                <td style="padding-right: 20px">
                    <apex:outputText >
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!germany}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Germany
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
                <td style="padding-right: 20px">
                    <apex:outputText >
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!russia}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Russia
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
            </tr>   
        </table>
        <p></p>
        <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<mark>* *</mark><b>USA will have access by default</b></p>

        <br/>

        <p><i><b>4 Please specify the data deletion date after the case/CCR is closed <mark>*</mark></b></i></p>
        <hr size="10px" color="black"/>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <apex:selectRadio value="{!selectedValue}" styleClass="radioClass">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding-right: 35px"><p>Immediate</p></td>
                            <td style="padding-right: 10px"><apex:selectOption itemValue="immediate"/></td>
                            <td style="padding-right: 10px"><p>30 Days</p></td><td style="padding-right: 35px"><apex:selectOption itemValue="30_days"/></td>
                            <td style="padding-right: 20px"><p>60 Days</p></td><td style="padding-right: 20px"><apex:selectOption itemValue="60_days"/></td>
                            <td style="padding-right: 20px"><p>90 Days</p></td><td style="padding-right: 20px"><apex:selectOption itemValue="90_days"/></td>
                            <td style="padding-right: 20px"><p>180 Days</p></td><td style="padding-right: 20px"><apex:selectOption itemValue="180_days"/></td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>                              
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange"
                                        action="{!checkSelectedValue}"
                                        reRender="none"/>
                </apex:selectRadio> 
            </tr>   
        </table>
        <table>
            <td style="padding-right: 20px">
                <apex:outputText >
                    <apex:inputCheckbox style="outline: 2px solid red;" id="squaredfour" value="{!Acknow_Check}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<t style="font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:11.4pt; color:#283747; "><b>You acknowledge that, to the best of your knowledge,
                    the information you have provided is correct and as such, Company will restrict your data submitted with
                    this request accordingly.
                    Your data wil be kept in a secure environment. We appreciate your cooperation.</b></t>
                </apex:outputText>
            </td>
        </table>
        <br/>

        <div style= "padding-left:325px">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Continue" id="submitCase" style="margin-right: 5px" class="btn btn-primary pull-right btn-cos" />
            <div class="divider"/>
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" id="cancelAttachment22" style="margin-right: 15px" class="btn btn-primary pull-right btn-cos" />
        </div>
    </apex:form>  
</div>
```

**Here is the controller:**

```
 public Pagereference submitClassificationForm()
{
  String caseId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('CaseID');
        List<Data_Classification_Form__c> dcfList=[SELECT Id, Customer_Name__c, Project_Name__c,CaseNumID__c,NDA_Reference_No__c, Export_Restrictions__c, X3rd_Party_Restrictions__c, ITAR__c, ECN_ECCN__c, I_Don_t_Know__c, X3E001__c, X3E002__c, X3E003__c, X3E991__c, X4E001__c, X4E992__c, X5E001__c, X5E991__c, X5E002__c, X5E992__c, EAR99__c, X9E515__c,restrict__c, Data_Deletion_Date__c  FROM Data_Classification_Form__c where CaseNumID__c=: caseId];
    Data_Classification_Form__c dcf = new  Data_Classification_Form__c();
   if(dcfList.size()> 0)
    {
        dcf.Id= dcfList[0].Id;
    }    
        dcf.Customer_Name__c = CustomerName;
        dcf.CaseNumID__c = caseId;
        dcf.Project_Name__c = ProjectName;
        dcf.NDA_Reference_No__c = nda;
        dcf.Export_Restrictions__c = ExportR;
        System.debug('***thirdParty ****'+thirdParty );
        dcf.X3rd_Party_Restrictions__c = thirdParty ;
        System.debug('***dcf.X3rd_Party_Restrictions__c***'+dcf.X3rd_Party_Restrictions__c);
        dcf.X3E001__c = E001;

        dcf.ITAR__c= itar;
        dcf.ECN_ECCN__c = eccn;
        dcf.I_Don_t_Know__c = idontknow;
        dcf.X3E002__c= E002;
        dcf.X3E003__c = E003;
        dcf.X3E991__c= E991;
        dcf.X4E001__c= fourE001;
        dcf.X4E992__c= fourE992;
        dcf.X5E001__c= fiveE001;
        dcf.X5E991__c= fiveE991;
        dcf.X5E002__c= fiveE002;
        dcf.X5E992__c= fiveE992;
        dcf.EAR99__c = EAR99;
        dcf.X9E515__c= nineE515;
        dcf.Other__c = others;
        dcf.ARM__c = ARM;
        dcf.Intel__c = Intel;
        dcf.TSMC__c = TSMC;
        dcf.IBM_Global_Foundries__c = IBM_Global;
        dcf.Synopsys__c = Synopsys;
        dcf.Japan__c = japan;
        dcf.India__c = india;
        dcf.China__c = china;
        dcf.Germany__c = germany;
        dcf.Russia__c = russia;
        dcf.Acknow_Check__c = Acknow_Check;
        dcf.Data_Deletion_Date__c = selectedValue;

        System.debug('***restrict***'+restrict);
        dcf.restrict__c = restrict;
        upsert dcf;
        PageReference pageRef=new PageReference('https://pramita-prd-cos.cs14.force.com/COSCaseDetailPage?CaseID='+caseId+'&pageName=COSCaseDetailPage&isNewCase=false');
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;

}

public void checkSelectedValue()
{
    System.debug('Selected value is: ' +selectedValue);
}
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far, this makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Standard **Save** functionality in submit button , Create your own method in controller and call that method through submit button.

Inside controller method **Insert your Object ;** and Do your stuff's for displaying data.

Answer (score 0):

In the `submitClassificationForm()`, after upserting the data to the database, you are redirecting it to another page. Therefore, the form is getting blank.

To get the same form, do not redirect to any other page.

Updated code:

```
public void submitClassificationForm()
{
  String caseId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('CaseID');
        List<Data_Classification_Form__c> dcfList=[SELECT Id, Customer_Name__c, Project_Name__c,CaseNumID__c,NDA_Reference_No__c, Export_Restrictions__c, X3rd_Party_Restrictions__c, ITAR__c, ECN_ECCN__c, I_Don_t_Know__c, X3E001__c, X3E002__c, X3E003__c, X3E991__c, X4E001__c, X4E992__c, X5E001__c, X5E991__c, X5E002__c, X5E992__c, EAR99__c, X9E515__c,restrict__c, Data_Deletion_Date__c  FROM Data_Classification_Form__c where CaseNumID__c=: caseId];
    Data_Classification_Form__c dcf = new  Data_Classification_Form__c();
   if(dcfList.size()> 0)
    {
        dcf.Id= dcfList[0].Id;
    }    
        dcf.Customer_Name__c = CustomerName;
        dcf.CaseNumID__c = caseId;
        dcf.Project_Name__c = ProjectName;
        dcf.NDA_Reference_No__c = nda;
        dcf.Export_Restrictions__c = ExportR;
        System.debug('***thirdParty ****'+thirdParty );
        dcf.X3rd_Party_Restrictions__c = thirdParty ;
        System.debug('***dcf.X3rd_Party_Restrictions__c***'+dcf.X3rd_Party_Restrictions__c);
        dcf.X3E001__c = E001;

        dcf.ITAR__c= itar;
        dcf.ECN_ECCN__c = eccn;
        dcf.I_Don_t_Know__c = idontknow;
        dcf.X3E002__c= E002;
        dcf.X3E003__c = E003;
        dcf.X3E991__c= E991;
        dcf.X4E001__c= fourE001;
        dcf.X4E992__c= fourE992;
        dcf.X5E001__c= fiveE001;
        dcf.X5E991__c= fiveE991;
        dcf.X5E002__c= fiveE002;
        dcf.X5E992__c= fiveE992;
        dcf.EAR99__c = EAR99;
        dcf.X9E515__c= nineE515;
        dcf.Other__c = others;
        dcf.ARM__c = ARM;
        dcf.Intel__c = Intel;
        dcf.TSMC__c = TSMC;
        dcf.IBM_Global_Foundries__c = IBM_Global;
        dcf.Synopsys__c = Synopsys;
        dcf.Japan__c = japan;
        dcf.India__c = india;
        dcf.China__c = china;
        dcf.Germany__c = germany;
        dcf.Russia__c = russia;
        dcf.Acknow_Check__c = Acknow_Check;
        dcf.Data_Deletion_Date__c = selectedValue;

        System.debug('***restrict***'+restrict);
        dcf.restrict__c = restrict;
        upsert dcf;

}
```

In this way, the user will be in the same page.